# Unir dos consultas y ordenar en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Necesito obtener los datos de la tabla `info`, ordenar los primero 6 meses y unir los datos de la tabla historia de `where tipo=1` después los otros 6 meses restantes y `where tipo=2`.

No sé si se puede unir en una consulta `MySQL` o unirlos en un mismo array `PHP`.

Quisiera unir estas dos consultas.

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE id_cli=10

SELECT cli_id,fecha_top,calculo FROM historia WHERE cli_id=10 and tipo between 1 and 2
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor edita y coloca lo que tratas de obtener, pues no me queda claro del todo

Comment: Viendo la tercer tabla, pareciera que es el resultado que busca obtener, es decir, a la primer consulta busca agregar los resultados coloreados de la segunda consulta, al parecer ordenados por `tipo`. Hay que esperar a que responda, porque esto es lo que yo supongo

Comment: sí eso es la consulta que quisiera obtener. @Marcos

Comment: @Carlos, por favor edita tu pregunta y aclara esto allí, ya que los comentarios son temporales y eventualmente se eliminan

Comment: Editada para mejor comprensión.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es:

- Un [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) entre ambos `SELECT`
- Crear columnas con alias para los datos que no existen en las otras tablas (`ej: "" as calculo`)
- Para que al ordenar todos los registros y que los de la tabla `historia` queden debajo de los "6 primeros meses", puede crear un `IF(tipo = 1, 6, 12) AS mes`
- Finalmente basta con ordenar todos los registros por la columna `mes`

#### Ejemplo:

```
(SELECT id_cli, nombre, fecha, mes, descripcion, bono, "" as calculo, valor
   FROM info 
   WHERE id_cli=10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT cli_id, "", fecha, IF(tipo = 1, 6, 12) AS mes, "", "", calculo, ""
   FROM historia 
   WHERE cli_id=10 
       AND tipo IN (1,2))
ORDER BY mes ASC
```

<kbd>[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c430e/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto le puede servir:

```
select 
i.id_cli,i.nombre,i.fecha,i.mes,i.descripcion,i.bono,h.calculo,i.valor
from info i,historia h  where i.id_cli=h.id and i.id_cli=10 and h.id=10
```

Si necesita mas condiciones las agrega como

```
[i.campo ]=>tabla info
```

o

```
[h.campo]=> tabla historia
```